# Как получить аватарку пользователя Telegram в Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, telegram

Пишу телеграм бота при помощи библиотеки pyTelegrambotApi. Для определённой команды мне нужно получить аватарку пользователя, который отправил данную команду боту. Но как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36733263/ посмотреть на метод getUserProfilePhotos, хоть там и другой язык, но API общее

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В API есть метод [getUserProfilePhotos](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getuserprofilephotos). [Нашел его в другой библиотеке](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html?highlight=getUserProfilePhotos#telegram.Bot.get_user_profile_photos) - [python-telegram-bot](/questions/tagged/python-telegram-bot) (*просто, я на ней пишу ботов :)*)

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/6b5a73d6991c9d969381d665f04eb456bfc71574/telegram_bot_examples/get_user_profile_photos.py#L29)

```
def on_request(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    message = update.effective_message
    user_id = update.effective_user.id

    result = context.bot.get_user_profile_photos(user_id)

    photos = result['photos']
    if not photos:
        message.reply_text('No profile photos!')
        return

    for photo_sizes in photos:
        photo = max(photo_sizes, key=lambda x: x['width'])
        file_id = photo['file_id']
        message.reply_photo(file_id, caption=file_id)
```

#### Объясняю:

Метод вернул объект [UserProfilePhotos](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#userprofilephotos), для теста закинул две случайные фотографии в профиль и они вернулись в таком виде:

```
{
    'total_count': 2,
    'photos': [[{
                'height': 160,
                'file_unique_id': 'AQAD1acxG_SOVA8AAQ',
                'file_id': 'AgACAgIAAxUAAWF9mWiRH4LUDnqk3v_ivfIu-olMAALVpzEb9I5UD4fMFih4no10AQADAgADYQADIQQ',
                'file_size': 12619,
                'width': 160
            }, {
                'height': 320,
                'file_unique_id': 'AQAD1acxG_SOVA9n',
                'file_id': 'AgACAgIAAxUAAWF9mWiRH4LUDnqk3v_ivfIu-olMAALVpzEb9I5UD4fMFih4no10AQADAgADYgADIQQ',
                'file_size': 31416,
                'width': 320
            }, {
                'height': 640,
                'file_unique_id': 'AQAD1acxG_SOVA8B',
                'file_id': 'AgACAgIAAxUAAWF9mWiRH4LUDnqk3v_ivfIu-olMAALVpzEb9I5UD4fMFih4no10AQADAgADYwADIQQ',
                'file_size': 52226,
                'width': 640
            }
        ], [{
                'height': 160,
                'file_unique_id': 'AQAD1KcxG_SOVA8AAQ',
                'file_id': 'AgACAgIAAxUAAWF9mWhYGYeDL7f4x82FqQEl1Jx5AALUpzEb9I5UD9H1YocVy_iAAQADAgADYQADIQQ',
                'file_size': 3242,
                'width': 160
            }, {
                'height': 320,
                'file_unique_id': 'AQAD1KcxG_SOVA9n',
                'file_id': 'AgACAgIAAxUAAWF9mWhYGYeDL7f4x82FqQEl1Jx5AALUpzEb9I5UD9H1YocVy_iAAQADAgADYgADIQQ',
                'file_size': 6790,
                'width': 320
            }, {
                'height': 640,
                'file_unique_id': 'AQAD1KcxG_SOVA8B',
                'file_id': 'AgACAgIAAxUAAWF9mWhYGYeDL7f4x82FqQEl1Jx5AALUpzEb9I5UD9H1YocVy_iAAQADAgADYwADIQQ',
                'file_size': 11708,
                'width': 640
            }
        ]]
}
```

Как видно, каждая картинка описана несколькими размерами, в коде использовал `max`, чтобы вернуть картинку с наибольшей шириной. А чтобы отправить картинку можно использовать значение `file_id`, тогда будет использована картинка с сервера

#### Результат

Написал боту и тот отправил те 2 картинки с подписью с значением `file_id`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ого, спасибо большое!

Comment: @Darksnaper, пожалуйста :)